# Determining an explicit line bundle over surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

The following is an  explicitly defined complex line bundle $E\to\Sigma$ over a closed surface:
View $\Sigma$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and consider its Gauss map $n:\Sigma\to S^2$ given by (outward-pointing) unit normal vectors, $n(p)=(n_1(p),n_2(p),n_3(p))$. Given the Pauli matrices $\tau_1 =\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
0&i\\ i&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and $\tau_2=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
0&-1\\ 1&0
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and $\tau_3=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix}
i&0\\ 0&-i
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, define $\tilde{n}:\Sigma\to M_2(\mathbb{C})$ by $p\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^3n_j(p)\tau_j$. Then $E$ is the subbundle of $\Sigma\times\mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $\lbrace (p,v)\;|\;\tilde{n}(p)v=iv\rbrace$.

**Is $E$ familiar, say $E\cong T\Sigma$ or $E\cong\underline{\mathbb{C}}$?**

This is an instance where brute force seems like the only way to approach these questions, as everything is written pointwise instead of being abstractly defined. But I don't have a brute force method at hand.

[Edit] I think I can show that $c_1(E)=-1$ for $\Sigma=S^2$, so that it's neither $TS^2$ nor $S^2\times\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The only way I can imagine doing this is to compute the degree of the Gauss map $n$ and relate it, by Poincaré-Hopf, to the sum of the indices of a tangent vector field (or, if you prefer, holomorphic $1$-form on a compact Riemann surface). Of course, $c_1$ can be represented by a $2$-form, given by a multiple of the hermitian curvature form of the bundle (which, in turn, can be related to the associated curvature $2$-form of the Riemannian metric). None of this is so brute-forceable.

Comment: It would be a good idea to come up with a description of what that bundle is. For example, you are using $n$ to construct a map $\Sigma\to\mathfrak{su}(2)$, really. What does it mean?

Comment: On the other hand,if you do this when the surface is the sphere, then the general case is just the pullback along the Gauss map. Notice that this means that the first Chern class is just the degree of the Gauss map (which is half the Euler characteristic)  times the Chern class for the sphere.

Comment: Have you tried thinking of the Gauss map instead as the complexified Gauss map to the conic $\sum z_j^2=0$ in $\Bbb CP^2$? Is there a better interpretation?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah right! I did not think to look at the pull-back, since the Gauss map was getting intertwined with the Pauli matrices. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that $E$ is a square root of $T\Sigma$ (in particular, it is only trivial if $\Sigma=\mathbb T^2$). We compute $c_1(E\to S^2)$ using Chern-Weil theory, and then note that $E\to\Sigma$ is the pullback of $E\to S^2$ via $n$.